# Is it right to use "in complaint to" instead of "to complain about"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

I started a letter with:

Dear Sir/Madam,
I am writing this letter **in complaint to** the poor service and inappropriate food quality and price I received from your restaurant.

As I was checking my writing, I mentioned that every sample online begins like this:

I am writing this letter **to complain about** blah blah blah...

I am not sure if my statement is rare or incorrect. Please brighten me.

*by the way, English is a foreign language to me, so please excuse any wrong use of language and feel free to correct each and any mistakes I may have made throughout this question. Any advice is appreciated.*

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Never right. You must always use *to complain about*.

That said, no native speaker would ever misunderstand *in complaint to* so you should be fairly safe unless your letter goes to an unhelpful, non-native employee.

As you suspected, there are plenty of other errors in your post but this isn't the place for them… you need to find a teacher or translator.

Answer (score 1):

To complain about is definitely the better choice.  It's better to use a verbal form (infinitive) "to complain" rather than a noun "complaint"